# Recursively move specific files in nested directories to a name derived from the path

Tags: bash, rename, cp, mv

I have some files in different nested directories. All the files are named `Analysis.mzXML`. I would like to have them all in one place, while changing the name of each one to something different, depending on the directories it was previously saved on.

I know that moving a file and giving it the directory name has been shown earlier in other questions such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16541582/finding-multiple-files-recursively-and-renaming-in-linux), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14306117/rename-files-in-multiple-directories-to-the-name-of-the-directory) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25973504/bash-batch-rename-nested-directories-or-files-with-the-same-name).

However, they only use the programs to move them one directory out and only change the name based on that one directory. In my case, I would like the files to be renamed using the entire route of nested directories

The files are all saved as follows:

```
/dir1/dir2/dir3/dir4/dir5/dir6/Analysis.mzXML
```

Each `Analysis.mzXML` is nested in folders of different names. However, `dir6` happens to have the same name for all files, and since it no offers valuable information I would like to skip it.

My expectation is that by running some command or script I can get all these files named with their specific route as follows:

```
/dir1_dir2_dir3_dir4_dir5.mzXML
```

I have been just getting started with bash and I am not sure how to come around this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question, as written, suggests that
you want to search the entire filesystem for `Analysis.mzXML` files,
even if they appear in `/lib/perl5/5.14/Unicode/Collate/Locale`,
`/proc/sys/net/ipv4/conf/all`, `/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cache`,
`/usr/share/doc/cmake/html/_sources`,
or similarly unlikely / inappropriate places —
and that you want to move the files into the root directory,
which also seems unlikely / inappropriate. 
I assumed that you are working from some other directory.

Run this command:

```
find . -mindepth 7 -maxdepth 7 -type f -name Analysis.mzXML -exec sh -c 'for arg do echo mv -i -- "$arg" "$(echo "$arg" | sed -e "s|^\./||" -e "s|/dir6/Analysis\.mzXML|.mzXML|" -e "s|/|_|g")"; done' sh {} +
```

You can leave out the `-mindepth 7 -maxdepth 7`
if you’re sure that all the `Analysis.mzXML` files are at the seventh level. 
This command finds all `Analysis.mzXML` files at the seventh level
and passes them to a mini-shell script. 
That takes each pathname, strips off the `./` at the beginning
and the `dir6` at the end, along with the `Analysis` part of the filename,
and changes all the remaining `/` characters to `_`. 
This should produce an output something like this:

```
mv -i -- ./dir1/dir2/dir3/dir4/dir5/dir6/Analysis.mzXML dir1_dir2_dir3_dir4_dir5.mzXML
mv -i -- ./the/quick/brown/fox/jumps/dir6/Analysis.mzXML the_quick_brown_fox_jumps.mzXML
mv -i -- ./over/the/lazy/dog/foo bar/dir6/Analysis.mzXML over_the_lazy_dog_foo bar.mzXML
```

If this looks right, run the command again,
but delete the first `echo` (i.e., change `echo mv` to just `mv`).

Notes:

- This doesn’t verify that
  the sixth level directory is actually called `dir6`. 
  If it finds an `Analysis.mzXML` file
  in `dir11/dir12/dir13/dir14/dir15/dir16`, it will rename that file
  to `dir11_dir12_dir13_dir14_dir15_dir16_Analysis.mzXML`
  rather than `dir11_dir12_dir13_dir14_dir15.mzXML`.
- The `-i` will cause `mv` to ask for confirmation
  if it tries to move a file to a name that already exists.
- The `--` should protect you against arguments that begin with **`-`**. 
  This shouldn’t be an issue, since `$arg` should always begin with `./`.
- If you really want to do this from the filesystem root, that should work. 
  Just `cd /` and follow the above instructions.

Afterthought:
This might fail if you have a directory named `Analysis.mzXML`. 
So don’t do that.

Comment: Thank very much you for your thorough explanation of the commands. You are correct; I do indeed intend to search a specific directory, not my entire system. How can I be more clear about this in future questions?
I will run this as soon as I can and get back to you in a few hours.

Answer (score 1):

If you're moving only one file with `mv`, you specify the source filename and then the target filename **OR** the target directory if you want it to have the same name in a different directory.  e.g.

```
mv /path/to/Analysis.mzXML /new/directory/new-filename.mzXML
```

or (keeping the same filename in the new directory):

```
mv /path/to/Analysis.mzXML /new/directory/
```

If you're moving multiple files, the target **MUST** be a directory.  e.g.

```
 mv /path/to/*.mzXML /new/directory/
```

The same is true if you want to copy a file or files, with `cp` rather than `mv`.

Comment: Thank you, I will use the second option then. How can I give it the file derived from the path? The solution includes awk in many cases but it gives it the file name of the directory searched being searched. Since this is nested and I want to include some names and not all, I do not know how to modify it so that each .mzXML file is changed correctly.

Comment: i have no idea what you mean by "the file derived from the path".  BTW, if you want to do very complex renames, then you can use the `rename` utility (the `perl` version, not the one in `util-linux`) - anything you can do in perl that ends up modifying $_ can be used to rename files.

Comment: I meant filename.

Comment: With all due respect, I’m soooooooo tempted to flag this as “not an answer”.  The question seems to be asking about renaming `foo/bar/Analysis.mzXML` to `foo-bar`.  While your post is relevant, I don’t see how it comes close to answering the question.  P.S. Why do you say `*.mzXML` when the question says that *all* the files are named `Analysis.mzXML`?

Comment: 1. The OP's question is barely coherent and extremely difficult to make sense of.  It should probably be on hold as Unclear.   The best I could figure out was that he didn't know the conventions for specifying sources and targets for `mv`.  He seemed to appreciate having that spelled out in my answer.  2. Why *.mzXML? There's a conditional: "if you're moving multiple files".  If someone doesn't know how to mv a single file, it's a safe bet that they could use some help with mv-ing multiple files too. 3. Also, even after 5+ readings, I never noticed that he said all filenames are the same.

Comment: i guess i got distracted by trying to figure out what he meant by `unnecessary_dir`, and whether there was any particular rule for identifying whether a directory was necessary or unnecessary, or if the unwanted dir name was just an arbitrary string or a set of arbitrary string(s).

Comment: I will edit my question for clarity soon when I find a moment. I now see how convoluted it is. Thank you for your input. I now see that I want to create a way to generate a name that can skip some folders and not others while moving the Analysis. mzXml files. I will strive to be more clear in future posts.